# The neo4j cypher shell and the browser connections are working but the golang client connection is not working

Tags: neo4j, cypher, centos7

I have disabled the authentication on my neo4j server, so I can connect using the cypher shell using no credentials as it follows and is working.

```
$ ./bin/cypher-shell -a 192.168.0.89
```

This is how I'm declaring my driver and the session, I also tried using neo4j://* instead of bolt://*:

```
driver, err := neo4j.NewDriver("bolt://192.168.0.89:7687", neo4j.NoAuth())
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}
defer driver.Close()

session, _ := driver.NewSession(neo4j.SessionConfig{AccessMode: neo4j.AccessModeWrite})
defer session.Close()
```

But that doesn't work either. I'm getting this error when running the hello world from the neo4j olang driver page https://neo4j.com/developer/go/

```
TLS error: Remote end closed the connection, check that TLS is enabled on the server
```

There are the logs of the server when it starts:

```
2021-03-07 23:17:23.227+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 4.2.3 ========
2021-03-07 23:17:24.119+0000 INFO  Performing postInitialization step for component 'security-users' with version 2 and status CURRENT
2021-03-07 23:17:24.119+0000 INFO  Updating the initial password in component 'security-users'  
2021-03-07 23:17:24.243+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 192.168.0.89:7687.
2021-03-07 23:17:25.139+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://192.168.0.89:7474/
2021-03-07 23:17:25.140+0000 INFO  Started.
```

These are all my config settings:

```
dbms.connector.bolt.advertised_address=192.168.0.89:7687
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true                                                                
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=192.168.0.89:7687                                                                
dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=DISABLED                                                                
dbms.connector.http.advertised_address=192.168.0.89:7474
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true                                                 
dbms.connector.http.listen_address=192.168.0.89:7474                                                               
dbms.connector.https.enabled=false                                                             
dbms.default_advertised_address=192.168.0.89
dbms.default_database=neo4j                                                               
dbms.default_listen_address=192.168.0.89                                                      
dbms.directories.import=/home/eduardo/NEO4J/import                                                       
dbms.directories.neo4j_home=/home/eduardo/NEO4J
dbms.jvm.additional=-Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true
dbms.security.auth_enabled=false
dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy=1 days                                                          
dbms.tx_state.memory_allocation=ON_HEAP
dbms.windows_service_name=neo4j
```

Again, I can connect to the same host and the browser is also working fine:
[image]
Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone looking for the answer, the bolt driver will try to use TLS by default and since in my case is not configured, the encryption needs to be disabled in the driver constructor call.

```
driver, err := neo4j.NewDriver("bolt://192.168.0.89:7687", neo4j.NoAuth(), func(c *neo4j.Config) { c.Encrypted = false })
```

Hope this helps other people experiencing the same issue :)

Answer (score 2):

Adding to your answer: it is likely you're using the v1.x of the Go driver. If you switch to using the v4.x driver instead, you will not have to specify this config value.

You can upgrade by simply adding `v4` in your import statement like so:

```
import github.com/neo4j/neo4j-go-driver/v4/neo4j
```

More info: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-go-driver/blob/4.2/MIGRATIONGUIDE.md